# Merging dictionaries - Incompatible type error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I've been trying to merge two NSDictionaries for a couple hours now. Searched and found that I can use `[NSMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:]`.

```
    NSDictionary *areaAttributes = [[area entity] attributesByName];
    NSDictionary *gpsAttributes = [[gps entity] attributesByName];

    NSMutableDictionary *areaAttributesM = [areaAttributes mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *gpsAttributesM = [gpsAttributes mutableCopy];

    NSMutableDictionary *combinedAttributes =  [areaAttributesM addEntriesFromDictionary:gpsAttributesM];
```

But I get the error:

```
Initializing 'NSMutableDictionary *_strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'
```

So this is saying that `[areaAttributesM addEntriesFromDictionary:gpsAttributesM]` returns `void`? Is my understanding correct? And why is it returning void?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (void)addEntriesFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)otherDictionary
```

As to why, that's simple: Functions that mutate an object in place in Cocoa usually return void, so you can easily distinguish them from functions that return a different object.

Also, there's no reason to `mutableCopy` the `gpsAttributes` dictionary; it's just being used as the argument to `-[addEntriesFromDictionary:]`, which doesn't need to be mutable.

So, the right way to do this is:

```
NSDictionary *areaAttributes = [[area entity] attributesByName];
NSDictionary *gpsAttributes = [[gps entity] attributesByName];

NSMutableDictionary *combinedAttributes = [areaAttributes mutableCopy];
[combinedAttributes addEntriesFromDictionary:gpsAttributes];
```

You may want to wrap this up in a function (or a method in a category on `NSDictionary`), if you do if often:

```
NSDictionary *mergeDictionaries(NSDictionary *lhs, NSDictionary *rhs) {
    NSMutableDictionary *ret = [lhs mutableCopy];
    [ret addEntriesFromDictionary:rhs];
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: The line `[combinedAttributes addEntriesFromDictionary:gpsAttributes];` is giving me this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 'The key 'latitude' is not defined for this NSKnownKeysDictionary'`

Comment: `latitude` is a key in `gpsAttributes`. Shouldn't `addEntriesFromDictionary` add this key to `areaAttributes`?

Comment: Ah, you're not dealing with regular dictionaries, but with dictionaries that have a fixed set of keys, using the undocumented `NSKnownKeysDictionary`. That's a separate issue… but I see you wrote a separate question about that, so I'll answer over there.

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation, addEntriesFromDictionary tells that:

If both dictionaries contain the same key, the receiving dictionary’s previous value object for that key is sent a release message, and the new value object takes its place.
You need to use setObject to add each object to the dictionary.YOu need to loop through the keys of one dictionary and add it to the final dictionary.

Even setObject tells the same:

The key for value. The key is copied (using copyWithZone:; keys must conform to the NSCopying protocol). If aKey already exists in the dictionary, anObject takes its place.
You cannot have two same keys in the dictionary. All keys in the dictionary are unique.

If you still want to have the same key-value in the dictionary, you must use a different key.

For example, you have two dictionaries with following values:

```
NSDictionary *dict1=@{@"hello":@"1",@"hello2" :@"2"};
NSDictionary *dict2=@{@"hello":@"1",@"hello2":@"2",@"hello3":@"1",@"hello6":@"2",@"hello4":@"1",@"hello5" :@"2"};

 NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict1];
    for (id key in dict2.allKeys){
        for (id subKey in dict1.allKeys){
            if (key==subKey) {
                [mutableDict setObject:dict2[key] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ext-%@",key]];
            }else{
                [mutableDict setObject:dict2[key] forKey:key];
            }
        }
    }
```

and by the end of this loop, your new mutable dictionaries will have the follwoing key-values:

```
{
    "Ext-hello" = 1;
    "Ext-hello2" = 2;
    hello = 1;
    hello2 = 2;
    hello3 = 1;
    hello4 = 1;
    hello5 = 2;
    hello6 = 2;
}
```

As you can see, hello, and hello2 keys are renamed as Ext-hello1, Ext-hello2. form the dict1, and you still have all the dict2 values added to your mutable dict.

IF you don't want to add a new key, then you can add the values into an arrya and add that array to the dictionary. YOu can modify the for-loop to:

```
for (id key in dict2.allKeys){
    for (id subKey in dict1.allKeys){
        if (key==subKey) {
            NSMutableArray *myArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [myArr addObject:dict1[subKey]];
            [myArr addObject:dict2[key]];
            [mutableDict setObject:myArr forKey:key];
        }else{
            [mutableDict setObject:dict2[key] forKey:key];
        }
    }
}
```

And now you will have the values merged into an array:

```
{
    hello =     (
        1,
        1
    );
    hello2 = 2;
    hello3 = 1;
    hello4 = 1;
    hello5 = 2;
    hello6 = 2;
}
```

In this way, the number of keys will be same, and the values for the same key will be added as an array.